# Android;How to populate a ListView via Cursor

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a Database with a table called users(_id,name).
I am using the following method to get all the records in the ascending order of names

```
public Cursor getAllNames() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME },
            null, null, null, KEY_NAME+" ASC", null);
}
```

Now i am retrieving the Cursor in the List Activity as follows

```
DBAdapter db= new DBAdapter(this);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lview);
    ListView l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    db.open();
    Cursor c=db.getAllNames();
    db.close();
}
```

I am trying to use Simple Cursor Adapter to iterate thru the names and assign it to the List View. But since it has be depreciated how to achieve the same ?

Comment: https://github.com/lalit3686/CursorAdapter

Comment: @LalitPoptani is it an example code ?

Comment: yes you can just download and check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom Adapter that extends BaseAdapter and holds an ArrayList of items.
After you call the getAllNames() and you have all your items in the Cursor, iterate over the Cursor and put all those items in the ArrayList from the CustomAdapter. Then just set the CustomAdapter as the ListView adapter.

Comment: I am new to android. So can u please show some sample syntax, so that i can get the solution.

Comment: @Andrew, the better approach is to use SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: Indeed. This is just an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

SimpleCursorAdapter hasn't been deprecated, [one of it's constructors has](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29). If you want to attach Cursor data to a ListView then I strongly suggest the SimpleCursorAdapter option since it's the most easy way to do it. I believe the new SimpleCursorAdapter is offered in the v4 support library.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is no need to copy all the items just to display them in the ListView.